# Lapply function does not work for my matrices

Tags: r

### The problem:

I have a list of matrices. I would like to convert all the rows, unless the last row, to zero. I tried the `lapply` function but it does not work as expected.

### Example:

```
x <- matrix(3,4,4)
y <- matrix(5,4,5)
z <- list(x,y)
NewZ <- lapply(1:2, function(i) z[[i]][-nrow(z[[i]]), ] <- 0)
```

The lapply returns me this:

```
> NewZ
[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1] 0
```

I would like to get matrices like this:

```
> z[[1]][-nrow(z[[1]]),] <- 0
> z[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    3    3    3    3
> z[[2]][-nrow(z[[2]]),] <- 0

> z[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    5    5    5    5    5
```

Where is my mistake? any idea, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `lapply()` like a `for` loop. `lapply` loops through the list on its own, no need to use indexing:

```
NewZ <- lapply(z, function(x){
  x[-nrow(x),] <- 0
  return(x)
})

> NewZ
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    3    3    3    3

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    5    5    5    5    5
```

Also, when you change specific parts of a list element with `lapply` (meaning you are using the `<-` operator within the call), you need to `return` the element.

Comment: In addition to this solution, you don't even need to assign the result value of `lapply` to your list. You can use the `<<-` assignement which assisgns values *globally* rather than in the environment of your `lapply` call:  `x[-nrow(x),] <<- 0`. The you can drop the `NewZ <- lapply(...` assignement.

Comment: @FloSchmo Then you will have a function with a side effect. (this is not congruent to the R scoping scheme.) `library("fortunes"); fortune(174)` or http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf Circle 6